# Cardboard and IR transmittance

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, infrared-radiation

Does infrared radiation transmit (not absorb & re-radiate) through cardboard in the IR-B or IR-C bands?

I know IR-A does not transmit well but am curious about the longer wavelengths and can't seem to find good data on it.

Comment: if youd like to test IR-A is detectable on camera and a remote control, IR B thermal cameras for 40 dollars on banggood and maybe an M17 at CO2 absorption wavelengths on banggood again for 20$. it may be observable with a lot of math

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have data, only personal experience. IR-B will be well-blocked by cardboard. The longer wavelengths of IR-C will transmit, especially for wavelengths outside the water absorption bands. But, it will generally be pretty lossy, and you wouldn’t want your cardboard too thick.